# .net core health-checks inject scoped dependencies

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, health-check

I would like to call a specific method in an injected class (Scoped) during the RunCheckAsync

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bf50999cd8e60d4c683b772dffa9898794a8433a/src/HealthChecks/HealthChecks/src/DefaultHealthCheckService.cs#L56

here the register for HealthChecks

`services.AddHealthChecks() .AddDbContextCheck<MyDbCtxContext>("dbContextChecks", null,HealthCheckTagsConstants.ReadinessTags);`

The connectionString related to my "MyDbCtxContext" is dynamic, I need to retrieve a metadata in the HttpRequest (the customer's identifier for example) and call the method "SetIdentifier" in my class injected.

I tried to create a middleware to retrieve the information and specify the identifier but the middleware is managed ouf of the scope created here

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bf50999cd8e60d4c683b772dffa9898794a8433a/src/HealthChecks/HealthChecks/src/DefaultHealthCheckService.cs#L78

In that point, there is 2 scopes

- When the HttpRequest is created (managed by the framework), the middleware retreive my class from that scope
- When the method RunCheckAsync is called

How I'm suppose to manage that ? How can I get my class in the second scope ?

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your contribution. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? I have the feeling you don't necessarily want to inject code in someone else their classes but are in fact looking for a way to on how to setup a multi tenant application with database segregation on a client / org level.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ebbelink , you are right the purpose for the "AddDbContextCheck" it's related to the segregation on a client / org level. But I have other check (like specific api call to external services related to the client) so the problem is not only on the DbContext, it's more complex. At the end, I would like to retrieve information from the HttpContext and use it in the scope created by the DefaultHealthCheckService

Comment: injecting code into someone elses is just not a really good idea. So could you please try and rephrase your question in what you actually want to achieve?